# How to convert a PDF file and display in image format (*.jpg or *.png) in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, image, pdf

I want to read pdf file and convert it to jpg and then display it as an image in the browser.  Is this possible in any way in Angular 6?

I have tried ng2-pdf-viewer and ng2-image-viewer.  But neither of them did conversion of pdf to image for me.  Is there any way or any npm package that can do this?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your pdf in base64 string and display it with `<img class="img-rounded" [src]="fileDataB64">` where fileDataB64 is your base64string extract from pdf :)
To me it's working.